# Why does Function.prototype.bind have two purposes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I recently wondered about why `Function.prototype.bind` was given two purposes, which after a little googling seems to be on purpose, as Dmitry Soshnikov explicitly states exactly the same in his [article about bind](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/notes/note-1-ecmascript-bound-functions/):

> The current implementation of the Function.prototype.bind has two purposes, which are the static bound this value and the partial application of a function. Let’s consider them.

It seems like a needless violation of the single responsibility principle and creates the following, often usage where you don't care about the value of this in the function:

```
f.bind(undefined, argA, argB);
```

So the question is whether this is just unfortunate design or if there is a good reason for this.

Comment: You could write Brendan Eich and ask him. I don't know how many people who actively work on the ES spec are frequenting SO.

Comment: Well the ES5 version of `Function.prototype.bind` is based on the Prototype.js method, which behaved similarly. Not sure about why it was decided to have this signature though.

Comment: @FelixKling good idea but I thought maybe this was discussed on the mailing list and my google skills just suck ;)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy are you sure it was intentionally based on Prototype.js ?

Comment: http://esdiscuss.org/topic/improving-function-prototype-bind

Comment: This is because `bind` was made largely to mimic existing de-facto standard popularized by Prototype.js. It was/is convenient, and you could argue that binding context and arguments through one method is not really a violation of SRP.

Comment: Im pretty sure my example shows that bind does two things, one of which you don't care when you want to partially apply and therefore violates srp.

Comment: JavaScript authors value cuteness, methods that work as Swiss Army Knives and saving typing a few characters over SRP.  In what other language would you hack the global variable $ and become a dominant library?  Sometimes this is a good decision, often not.